# Validation of array form fields in laravel 4 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can we validate form fields that are arrays? Take a look at the following code

UserPhone Model:

```php
 public static $rules= array(
    'phonenumber'=>'required|numeric',
    'isPrimary'=>'in:0,1'
)
...........
```

UserController:

```php
$validation = UserPhone::validate(Input::only('phonenumber')));


    if($validation->passes())
      {
         $allInputs = Input::only('phonenumber','tid');
         $loopSize = sizeOf($allInputs);

         for($i=0;$i<$loopSize;$i++)
         {

         $phone = UserPhone::find($allInputs['tid'][$i]);
         $phone->phonenumber = $allInputs['phonenumber'][$i];
         $phone->save();

        }

     return Redirect::to('myprofile')->with('message','Update OK');

  }
  else
  {
     return Redirect::to('editPhone')->withErrors($validation);

  } 

}
```

the `$validation` comes from a BaseModel which extends Eloquent.

In my view:

```php
 <?php $counter=1; ?>
          @foreach($phones as $thephone)

           <section class="col col-12">
              <label class="label">Phone Number {{$counter++}}</label>
              <label class="input">
              <i class="icon-append icon-phone"></i>
                 {{Form::text('phonenumber[]',$thephone->phonenumber)}}
                 {{Form::hidden('tid[]',$thephone->id)}}
              </label>
            </section>
          @endforeach
```

Everything is working fine and I get all the phone numbers I want in the Update Form, but I cannot update the model because the validation fails with the  message "Phonenumber must be a number".

I know that there is not a simple solution for validating array form fields and I tried to extend the validator class but with no success.

How can I validate this kind of fields?

Answer (score 25):

Here's the solution I use:

## Usage

Simply transform your usual rules by prefixing `each`. For example:

```
'names' => 'required|array|each:exists,users,name'
```

Note that the `each` rule assumes your field is an array, so don't forget to use the `array` rule before as shown here.

## Error Messages

Error messages will be automatically calculated by the singular form (using Laravel's `str_singular()` helper) of your field. In the previous example, the attribute is `name`.

## Nested Arrays

This method works out of the box with nested arrays of any depth in dot notation. For example, this works:

```
'members.names' => 'required|array|each:exists,users,name'
```

Again, the attribute used for error messages here will be `name`.

## Custom Rules

This method supports any of your custom rules out of the box.

## Implementation

### 1. Extend the validator class

```
class ExtendedValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    public function validateEach($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        // Transform the each rule
        // For example, `each:exists,users,name` becomes `exists:users,name`
        $ruleName = array_shift($parameters);
        $rule = $ruleName.(count($parameters) > 0 ? ':'.implode(',', $parameters) : '');

        foreach ($value as $arrayKey => $arrayValue)
        {
            $this->validate($attribute.'.'.$arrayKey, $rule);
        }

        // Always return true, since the errors occur for individual elements.
        return true;
    }

    protected function getAttribute($attribute)
    {
        // Get the second to last segment in singular form for arrays.
        // For example, `group.names.0` becomes `name`.
        if (str_contains($attribute, '.'))
        {
            $segments = explode('.', $attribute);

            $attribute = str_singular($segments[count($segments) - 2]);
        }

        return parent::getAttribute($attribute);
    }
}
```

### 2. Register your validator extension

Anywhere in your usual bootstrap locations, add the following code:

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new ExtendedValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

And that's it! Enjoy!

## Bonus: Size rules with arrays

As a comment pointed out, there's seems to be no easy way to validate array sizes. However, the Laravel documentation is lacking for size rules: it doesn't mention that it can count array elements. This means you're actually allowed to use `size`, `min`, `max` and `between` rules to count array elements.

Comment: Thank you. But when I run `$validator = \Validator::make(Input::all(), ['names' => 'required|array|each:exists,users,username']);` . It always return true even I don't fill anything.

Comment: The solution is to use `required|array|min:1|each...`. I updated my answer to mention why this works.

**Why it happens**: I agree your case might seem odd, but it's normal behaviour. You are passing an array object (PHP type `array()`), not null, so the field isn't empty (`required` passes). Your object is an array, so `array` passes. And finally, no element is in the array, so `each` doesn't perform any validation and passes.

Comment: In which folder do I create it?

Answer (score 9):

It works best to extend the Validator class and re-use the existing Validator functions:

```php
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{

    return new Validation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);

});

class Validation extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    /**
     * Magically adds validation methods. Normally the Laravel Validation methods
     * only support single values to be validated like 'numeric', 'alpha', etc.
     * Here we copy those methods to work also for arrays, so we can validate
     * if a value is OR an array contains only 'numeric', 'alpha', etc. values.
     *
     * $rules = array(
     *     'row_id' => 'required|integerOrArray', // "row_id" must be an integer OR an array containing only integer values
     *     'type'   => 'inOrArray:foo,bar' // "type" must be 'foo' or 'bar' OR an array containing nothing but those values
     * );
     *
     * @param string $method Name of the validation to perform e.g. 'numeric', 'alpha', etc.
     * @param array $parameters Contains the value to be validated, as well as additional validation information e.g. min:?, max:?, etc.
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {

        // Convert method name to its non-array counterpart (e.g. validateNumericArray converts to validateNumeric)
        if (substr($method, -7) === 'OrArray')
            $method = substr($method, 0, -7);

        // Call original method when we are dealing with a single value only, instead of an array
        if (! is_array($parameters[1]))
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);

        $success = true;
        foreach ($parameters[1] as $value) {
            $parameters[1] = $value;
            $success &= call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);
        }

        return $success;

    }

    /**
     * All ...OrArray validation functions can use their non-array error message counterparts
     *
     * @param mixed $attribute The value under validation
     * @param string $rule Validation rule
     */
    protected function getMessage($attribute, $rule)
    {

        if (substr($rule, -7) === 'OrArray')
            $rule = substr($rule, 0, -7);

        return parent::getMessage($attribute, $rule);

    }
}
```

Comment: I got a message: Undefined offset: 1 at line: if (!is_array($parameters[1]))

Answer (score 6):

### each()

It's not in the docs, but the 4.2 branch may have a simple solution [around line 220](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php).

Just like the `sometimes($attribute, $rules, callable $callback)` function, there is now an `each($attribute, $rules)` function.

To use it, the code would be something simpler than a `sometimes()` call:

```
$v->each('array_attribute',array('rule','anotherRule')); //$v is your validator
```

### Caveats

- **`sometimes()` and `each()` don't seem to be easily chainable with each other** so if you want to do specifically conditioned rules on array values, you're better off with the magic solutions in other answers for now.
- **`each()` only goes one level deep** which isn't that different from other solutions. The nice thing about the magic solutions is that they will go 0 or 1 level deep as needed by calling the base rules as appropriate so I suppose if you wanted to go 1 to 2 levels deep, you could simply merge the two approaches by calling `each()` and passing it a magic rule from the other answers.
- **`each()` only takes one attribute**, not an array of attributes as `sometimes()` does, but adding this feature to `each()` wouldn't be a massive change to the `each()` function - just loop through the `$attribute` and `array_merge()` `$data` and the `array_get()` result. Someone can make it a pull request on master if they see it as desirable and it hasn't already been done and we can see if it makes it into a future build.

Comment: Also, in the past, to generally deal with this problem in any version of laravel, I often just sanitized my input to not be arrays in the first place by running some loops on the input to pull out the things I want, adding to my validation rules array as I go. One particular advantage is that when the array key is not meaningful output (multi-selects) in the validator's error messages, you can insert something more meaningful based on the value at that key, leading to more comprehensible errors.

Comment: just a note. At each you should use array for rules parameter otherwise it wont work

Comment: @Parhs indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update to the code of Ronald, because my custom rules wouldn't work with the array extension. Tested with Laravel 4.1, default rules, extended rules, …

```
public function __call($method, $parameters) {
    $isArrayRule = FALSE;
    if(substr($method, -5) === 'Array') {
        $method = substr($method, 0, -5);
        $isArrayRule = TRUE;
    }

    //
    $rule = snake_case(substr($method, 8));

    // Default or custom rule
    if(!$isArrayRule) {
        // And we have a default value (not an array)
        if(!is_array($parameters[1])) {
            // Try getting the custom validation rule
            if(isset($this->extensions[$rule])) {
                return $this->callExtension($rule, $parameters);
            }

            // None found
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
        } // Array given for default rule; cannot be!
        else return FALSE;
    }

    // Array rules
    $success = TRUE;
    foreach($parameters[1] as $value) {
        $parameters[1] = $value;

        // Default rule exists, use it
        if(is_callable("parent::$method")) {
            $success &= call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);
        } else {
            // Try a custom rule
            if(isset($this->extensions[$rule])) {
                $success &= $this->callExtension($rule, $parameters);
            }

            // No custom rule found
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
        }
    }

    // Did any of them (array rules) fail?
    return $success;
}
```

Comment: Verified functional on Laravel 4.1. Better written than my attempt, haha.

Answer (score 1):

There are now array validation rules in case this helps anybody. It doesn't appear that these have been written up in the docs yet.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/6a2ad475cfb21d12936cbbb544d8a136fc73be97

Comment: These only cover very specific cases, but you are correct. The other answers provide a much more comprehensive set of "magic" functions.

Comment: Seems for Laravel 5 only

Comment: @Volatil3 - Considering L5 only came out this year, and I answered the question almost exactly 1 year ago - how is it for L5 only?

See tags in link:
v5.0.22  v5.0.16 v5.0.1 v5.0.0 v4.2.11 v4.2.0 v4.1.27 v4.1.18 v4.1.0 v4.0.9 v4.0.8 v4.0.7 v4.0.6

Comment: @Gravy pardon. Yes you are right. So setting rule like `'availability_date[]' => 'array|required',` will work?

Comment: @Gravy Also, do I need to write custom validator too?