# Laravel getting values from array for validation and storing in DB

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am sending values from view to controller

Here is my Script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var vehicle_data = [];
        $("#vehicle_submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            vehicle_data.push($("#_token").val());
            vehicle_data.push($("#VehicleNo").val());
            vehicle_data.push($("#VehicleName").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ URL::to('vehicle-process') }}",
                data: "vehicle_arr=" + vehicle_data,
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am sending the values VehicleNo and VehicleName to the `vehicle-process` controller as a single array named as vehicle_arr using POST Method.

Now in the controller :

```
public function vehicle_process() 
{
    $a = Input::except(array('_token')) ;
    $rule = array(
        'VehicleNo' => 'required',
        'VehicleSeats' => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($a, $rule);

    if ($validator - > fails()) {
        $messages = $validator - > messages();
        return $messages;
    }
    else
   {
        $table = new VehicleModel;
        $table->VehicleNo=$VehicleNo;  // How can i get the value of VehicleNo and Vehcle Name
        $table->save();
   }
```

The Validator can't able to analyze the name of the element i.e., VehicleNo or VehicleSeats,

So whenever i pass the data from view it was showing VeihcleNo required validator messages all the time.

Can i make the validator like

```
    $rule = array(
        $a['VehicleNo'] => 'required',
        $a['VehicleSeats'] => 'required'
    );
```

as i am storing the all the values in $a.

I even tested `return $a;` to view all elements in the controller it shows like

```
 Object {vehicle_arr: "wBNTzuTY20GL6BR147TIM9l8mxpCbgMAM7ok7fD4,EZ-55,35"}
```

### Is it possible to get values like

**$value = Input::post('VehicleNo');**

So, How can i get the values extract so that i can done with the validation and store in db

My Model just has the Table Name

So i just need the way to get the value of $VehicleNo to store in db. So that i can construct this

```
        $table->VehicleNo=$VehicleNo;
        $table->save();
```

### Update : It is ok even if i change the method to POST to GET in order to achieve my Result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161785/validation-of-array-form-fields-in-laravel-4-error

Comment: @Clonerworks : Thanks, But It didn't answer my question. I ask not only for validator but also to seperate each elements individually to store in db.

Comment: tried a foreach loop?

Comment: I tried foreach ($a as $val) {
    $val = $value * 2;
 } And tried to get the $val , but i am getting empty results

Comment: try returning $a from the function to the screen and see how is displays cause i think you need to go another layer deep

Comment: try printing Input::all() to see what values you are getting

Comment: I am getting Object {vehicle_arr: "1,2"} while i return the Input:all(); But i need to get the particular element i.e., second element while i have more inputs for validator and other purposes

Comment: Why not you `get` the values ? So that **value = Input::get('VehicleNo');**

Comment: ȿµŁƮɦąɲ ąŁŁąµȡƹƹɲ Yes Atleast please help in get method