# Validation input as array in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I create dynamic input by using jQuery

```
<input type="text" name="prices[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="prices[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="prices[]" value="3" />
```

I try with this code but It not work.

```
protected $rules = [
    'title'             => 'required|min:3',
    'state'             => 'required',
    'prices'            => 'required|integer',
    // 'prices[]'            => 'required|integer' // Or
];
```

Comment: You will have to build a custom validator rule that loops over the array. What exactly do you want to validate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161785/validation-of-array-form-fields-in-laravel-4-error - check the 3rd answer, works perfectly

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius I've followed Ronald Hulshof's guide but I got a message: Undefined offset: 1 at line: if (!is_array($parameters[1]))

Comment: I said check 3rd answer, not 2nd

Comment: Thank you, but I got this message: 502 Bad Gateway. I'm using Homestead