# Laravel validation of multiple images inputs from HTML form array

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-form

I have following fields in HTMl form,

```
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" name="images[]"></div>
```

When I submit the form then I get images[] array in PHP. I am using Laravel framework for form validation. I have been using validator and rules. But I want to apply rule of required and max size to each image from the above array. Thanks.

Comment: check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534413/image-array-validation-in-laravel-5/39346535#39346535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example code of my image validations:

```
// Handle upload(s) with input name "files[]" (array) or "files" (single file upload)

if (Input::hasFile('files')) {
    $all_uploads = Input::file('files');

    // Make sure it really is an array
    if (!is_array($all_uploads)) {
        $all_uploads = array($all_uploads);
    }

    $error_messages = array();

    // Loop through all uploaded files
    foreach ($all_uploads as $upload) {
        // Ignore array member if it's not an UploadedFile object, just to be extra safe
        if (!is_a($upload, 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile')) {
        continue;
        }

         $validator = Validator::make(
            array('file' => $upload),
            array('file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png|image|max:1000')
         );

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Collect error messages
            $error_messages[] = 'File "' . $upload->getClientOriginalName() . '":' . $validator->messages()->first('file');
        }
     }

    // Redirect, return JSON, whatever...
    return $error_messages;
} else {
    // No files have been uploaded
}
```