# Multiple file upload validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, multiple-file-upload

I have multiple input fields with multiple file upload for each field.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
   {
?>
<div class="col-md-3 addedClass">
     <label>Vehicle Images</label>
     <input type="file" name="vehicle_image[{{$i}}][]" multiple="multiple">
     @if($errors->has('vehicle_image'))
          <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{$errors->first('vehicle_image')}}</strong>
          </span>
     @endif
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have got files in the request like this:

```
"vehicle_image" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "citizenship.jpg"
      1 => "logo_vehicle.png"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "ae backend.jpg"
      1 => "logo_vehicle.png"
    ]
  ]
```

In this case, I have two input fields with 2/2 files. When I have tried to validate mime type for `only images` like this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
           'vehicle_image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096'
       ],$messages[
            // error messages 
      ]);
```

I have got following error:

`FatalThrowableError in ReservationController.php line 67: Cannot use [] for reading`

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the above code ?
Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What if you remove the blank $messages array

Comment: $this->validate($request,['vehicle_image' => 'mimes:mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096']);

Comment: I don't have that in my code. This is error while asking question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the blank $messages array and calling the function `all()` for the  inputs on the request.

```
$rules = [
    'vehicle_image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096'
];
$this->validate($request,$rules);
```

To display the default error message you would throw an exception using something like:

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
        return redirect('VIEWPATH.VIEWNAME')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Then to display the errors you can have something like the following in your blade view or template:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <h4>
      <i class="icon fa fa-warning fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <strong>Error!</strong> See error messages...
    </h4>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

or

```
@if(session()->has('errors'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4>Following errors occurred:</h4>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Let me try this one

Comment: Just curious is this blank array here intentional? `vehicle_image[{{$i}}][]`

Comment: Yes, because of multiple files uploaded through every input field

Comment: in that case you may need to validate using a custom rule that loops through the inputs array and validates those.

Comment: take a look at this article https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/ section "Adding Custom Validation Rules"

Comment: Or this may what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534413/image-array-validation-in-laravel-5#answer-31664727

Comment: Since I have images at 2 level deep so I should use 'vehicle.*.*' => 'mimes:.....'

Comment: same concept with another loop

Comment: validation works after my edits on your answer but, how display error messages on view ? Any idea

Answer (score 0):

just remove extra empty array index from the input field.

```
<input type="file" name="vehicle_image[{{$i}}]" multiple="multiple">



$this->validate($request, [
            'vehicle_image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:4096'
        ]);
```

and  `dd($errors)` see result