# How to create a validator laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

validation to input multiple files.

This is my validator script :

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'raport1.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png|max:1024', 
                    'raport2.*' =>'required|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png|max:1024'

   ]);
```

and this script multiple select form:

```
<input id="raport1" name="raport1[]" type="file"  class="btn-success" multiple />
```

and my form format:

```
<form name="store" id="store" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action ="{{ url('/storeform') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" files ="true">
```

the validator can not check my input file format.  please help me, thnks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating multiple files in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326282/validating-multiple-files-in-array)

Comment: already successfully, but now the problem is I can not print error messages.

This script error on the blade: {{$errors->insert-> first (' raport1 ')}}

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362031/multiple-file-upload-validation-in-laravel