# "Method [validateEach] does not exist" Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-4.2

I've created custom validator:

```
namespace App\Validators;

class PhoneValidationRule extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    public function validatePhone($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return preg_match("/^[\+]?[-()\s\d]{4,17}$/", $value);
    }
}
```

and registered it:

```
class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {


    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new PhoneValidationRule($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
...
```

and it works fine if i call it for field:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'emails' => 'required|each:email',
            'phone' => 'required|phone',
        ]);
```

but when i try to apply it for array:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'emails' => 'required|each:email',
            'phones' => 'required|each:phone',
        ]);
```

i get error message:

> error: {type: "BadMethodCallException", message: "Method
>   [validateEach] does not exist.",…} file:
>   "/home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php"
>   line: 2564 message: "Method [validateEach] does not exist." type:
>   "BadMethodCallException"

**what i'm doing wrong?**

Comment: This is the first time I see `each`. Is this a custom rule?

Comment: @Mozammil no, it's native - check [the line 231](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part: `required|each`.

There is no such thing as a `each` validation rule. Take a look at the docs for a list of available validation rules: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-email)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161785/validation-of-array-form-fields-in-laravel-4-error/24985805#24985805

Answer (score 0):

Validating an individual field

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'phone' => 'required|phone',
]);
```

Validating arrays

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'emails' => 'required|array',
    'emails.*' => 'email',
    'phones' => 'required|array',
    'phones.*' => 'phone',
]);
```

* Laravel 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

## each()

The problem was partially solved by straight calling native method `$v->each()` for custom rule `phone`:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
   'phones' => 'required|array',
]);

$validator->each('phones', ['required', 'phone']);
```

but it allows you to iterate validation only for arrays of values but not objects